# Если модель создалась успешно, создать еще модель Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

У меня вопрос.
Мне нужно создавать две модели при регистрации пользователя.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы если создание юзера прошло успешно, создавалась еще одна модель и записывала данные в другую таблицу бд.
При моем нынешнем подходе получается, что первая модель создается не зависимо от того, успешно ли прошла регистрация.

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{
    UserAccount::create([
        'account' => $data['account'],
        'subscription_flag' => 0,
    ]);
    
    return UserAuth::create([
        'account' => $data['account'],
        'password' =>$data['password'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Пишете код в котором добавляете проверку успешности создания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, нельзя в БД хранить не зашифрованный пароль. Используйте Hash:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
...
$password = Hash:make($request->password);
```

Или, хотя бы, Crypt:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
...
$password = Crypt:encryptString($request->password);
```

Разница в том, что Hash это "безвозвратное" шифрование пароля, вы не можете его дешифровать, а Crypt это шифрование с возможностью дешифровать его:

```
$password = Crypt:decryptString($user->password);
```

Теперь же, касательно вашего вопроса, при создании вы просто в переменную записываете модель

```
$user = UserAuth::create([
    'account' => $data['account'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
```

И теперь можно добавить проверку

```
if ($user) {
    UserAccount::create([
        'account' => $user->account,
        'subscription_flag' => 0,
    ]);
}
```

И, всё в месте:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
...
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = UserAuth::create([
        'account' => $data['account'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
    
    if ($user) {
        UserAccount::create([
            'account' => $data['account'],
            'subscription_flag' => 0,
        ]);
        return $user;
    }

    return ['error' => 'User not created'];   
}
```

Comment: Да храню то я в зашифрованном виде, у меня там вообще своя система, поэтому не стала выкладывать. А за ответ на мой вопрос спасибо, все работает прекрасно.

Comment: Пароль в модели шифруется на уровне сеттеров

Comment: @MoloF он шифруется где, кому, и как угодно, другое дело "хорошие практики".. И, это не уровень сеттеров, а мутаторами зовётся